# Javascript - Change name of all object keys in nested arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend

This is the array i get:

```
const packages = [
  {
    id: '641a1690-6c8b-4ada-ae97-8d82cc4fe7a3',
    name: 'com.sample',
    children: {
      id: 'd7384f60-e4ab-4a86-8e2e-0f66cc32f',
      name: 'child.computer.com',
      children: { id: 'e4ab-4a86-0f66cc32f560', name: 'child.com' }
    }
  },
  { id: 'd7384f60-e4ab-4a86-8e2e-0f66cc32f560', name: 'computer.com' },
  { id: 'ca7f972e-64ee-4cb0-80b9-1036fac69d32', name: 'java.util' }
];
```

So, it is an array of objects, and each object can have children, which again have id, name and possibly children (children is optional), and so on, it can be nested X times.
I want to change key names, id to key, name to title and children will remain children. So, my problem is that i don't know how to change keys inside children, i just change the first level and that is all.. It should be like:

```
{
    key: '641a1690-6c8b-4ada-ae97-8d82cc4fe7a3',
    title: 'com.sample',
    children: {
      key: 'd7384f60-e4ab-4a86-8e2e-0f66cc32f',
      title: 'child.computer.com',
      children: { key: 'e4ab-4a86-0f66cc32f560', title: 'child.com' }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Try reading `map` in array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using *Recursion*.

Check if the **value** of the [key-value] pair from the `Object#entries()` call is an *object*.

If so, call the `transformObj` function again *recursively* for that value. Else return the value as is.

And finally convert the array of [key-value] pairs back to an object by using `Object#fromEntries`:

```js
const packages = [{ id: '641a1690-6c8b-4ada-ae97-8d82cc4fe7a3', name: 'com.sample', children: { id: 'd7384f60-e4ab-4a86-8e2e-0f66cc32f', name: 'child.computer.com', children: { id: 'e4ab-4a86-0f66cc32f560', name: 'child.com' }}}, { id: 'd7384f60-e4ab-4a86-8e2e-0f66cc32f560', name: 'computer.com' }, { id: 'ca7f972e-64ee-4cb0-80b9-1036fac69d32', name: 'java.util' }];
const replacer = { "id": "key", "name" :"title"};
const transformObj = (obj) => {
  if(obj && Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Object.prototype){
    return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
          .map(([k, v]) => [replacer[k] || k, transformObj(v)])
    );
  }
  //Base case, if not an Object literal return value as is
  return obj;
}
console.log(packages.map(o => transformObj(o)));
```

Comment: Why if(obj && Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Object.prototype) check was necessary?

Comment: @RichardRublev check if the value is a nested object, if so we need to recursively transform the nested object as well. If it is a `string` or a `number` then we do not bother transforming.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to go through every object inside your array and recursively iterate through its keys. Then you can change the keys you want to change and iterate further through the childrens key.

```js
const packages = [{id: '641a1690-6c8b-4ada-ae97-8d82cc4fe7a3',name:'com.sample',children: {id: 'd7384f60-e4ab-4a86-8e2e-0f66cc32f',name: 'child.computer.com',children: { id: 'e4ab-4a86-0f66cc32f560', name: 'child.com' }}},{ id: 'd7384f60-e4ab-4a86-8e2e-0f66cc32f560', name: 'computer.com' },{ id: 'ca7f972e-64ee-4cb0-80b9-1036fac69d32', name: 'java.util' }];

const renameNestedObjects = (obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key, index) => {
    if (key == "id") {
      obj["key"] = obj["id"];
      delete obj["id"];
    }
    if (key == "name") {
      obj["title"] = obj["name"];
      delete obj["name"];
    }
    if (key == "children") {
        renameNestedObjects(obj["children"]);
    }
  });
}

console.log(packages);
packages.forEach(obj => { renameNestedObjects(obj); });
console.log(packages);
```

Comment: this also works, although i have chosen the first answer because it is more dynamic, but thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution of Fullstack Guy was good only for one-level transformation. Same for Olli's solution.
So for deep transformation the solution of Olli should be like this:

```
const renameNestedObjects = (obj) => {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach((key, index) => {
          if (key == 'id') {
            obj['key'] = obj['id'];
            delete obj['id'];
          }
          if (key == 'name') {
            obj['title'] = obj['name'];
            delete obj['name'];
          }
          if (key == 'children') {
            obj['children'].forEach((children) => renameNestedObjects(children));
          }
        });
      };
```

And if your initial array of objects is not extensible you may consider using this:

```
arrayOfObjects = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialIncomingNotExtensibleArrayOfObjects);
```

and after that to apply suggested transformation to this new arrayOfObjects.